# Java - Making hangman game

Tags: java, loops

I'm having a slight problem when trying to make a hangman game. I made a post regarding a different error before, but now I am running into a new one that I can't figure out. I'm trying to verify that the letter guess wasn't already entered. But it is skipping an entire section of the if/else statement. When I run this code:

public class TestingStuff {

```
static StringBuffer randomWord;
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
static int totalTries = 1;
static String guess;
static char finalGuess;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    randomWord = TestingStuff.sendGet();
    char[] guesses = new char[26];
    int length = randomWord.length();

    System.out.print("* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"
            + "\n*    Welcome to Hangman!    *"
            + "\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *");
    System.out.println("\nYou get 10 tries to guess the word by entering in letters!\n");
    System.out.println(randomWord);
    /*
     Cycles through the array based on tries to find letter
     */
    while (totalTries <= 10) {
        System.out.print("Try #" + totalTries + "\nWord: " + makeDashes(randomWord));

        //Right here: Search through the array of guesses, make it 26 characters to represent the alphabet
        //if the user guess equals an already guessed letter, add to try counter. If it's correct, then reveal the letter that is 
        //correct and do it again without adding to the try counter. 
        System.out.print("\nWhat is your guess? ");
        guess = console.nextLine();
        finalGuess = guess.charAt(0);
        guesses[totalTries - 1] = finalGuess; //Puts finalGuess into the array

            for (int i = 0; i < totalTries; i++) { //checks to see if the letter is already guessed
                if (guesses[i] != finalGuess) {
                    System.out.println(guesses[i]);
                    for (int j = 0; i < length; j++) { //scans each letter of random word
                        if (finalGuess == randomWord.charAt(j)) {
                            //put a method that swaps out dashes with the guessed letter
                            totalTries++;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Letter already guessed, try again! ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an output of this:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
*    Welcome to Hangman!    *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
You get 10 tries to guess the word by entering in letters!

ostracization
Try #1
Word: -------------
What is your guess? a
Letter already guessed, try again! 
Try #1
Word: -------------
What is your guess?
```

It's just saying that the letter is already guessed when there is an empty element in the array. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `if (guesses[i] != finalGuess) { } else { "Letter already guessed, try again! "}` is pretty clear. If you want to control an "empty" (what is empty?) element, then you have to add a condition for it.

Comment: @m0skit0 when I prompt the user to enter in a guess, I have it so it will place it into the array of char values. Is that not what I am doing here?

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through the code with your example (I strongly suggest you do this yourself with a debugger):

```
guesses[totalTries - 1] = finalGuess; // guesses[0] = 'a'
if (guesses[i] != finalGuess) // i = 0, guesses[0] = 'a', finalGuess = 'a'
else System.out.println("Letter already guessed, try again! ");
```

You can just move

```
guesses[totalTries - 1] = finalGuess; //Puts finalGuess into the array
```

at the end of the outermost `for` loop. There's no need to store a guess before having processed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The variable `totalTries` is initially 1. You read your guess and then you set `guesses[totalTries - 1]` to the character guessed, meaning `guesses[0]` is equal to `finalGuess`. Then you loop over `i` from 0 to `totalTries - 1` which is also 0. The loop is executed once and it is checked that the first entry is not `finalGuess`. But it is, we just set it.

If you use the for loop only to discover duplicate guesses, you could change  the condition in the first for-loop to `i < totalTries - 1` and it should work, but you need to move marking the hangman word below. For a minimal impact to your code, use m0skit0's solution.

Comment: I don't think your fix works because the problem happens at the first iteration and not at the last.

Comment: @m0skit0 Ah, you're right, I failed to notice that he does not only check for the duplicate guess, but also does the replacement in that for loop. In that case your solution is better. I will edit my solution to reflect my line of thinking better.